# Error page appears after placing the order on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Now I am working on WordPress site that has products that are sailed with WooCommerce plugin. All works fine only after choosing the product when I fill in the all information related to the order and submit this form it goes to error 404 page. But in admin panel this order appears only when I submit the form ir goes to error page.

Any help appreciated.
Was anyone who had this problem too?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if order received endpoints are properly set in woocommerce settings > checkout. Try saving the permalink again to flush it.

Comment: Thanks for the unswer I have just solved this problem.It is because of the permalink,  when I set the permalink to defalut all works ok.